# Angular Material Slider Showing up wierdly

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, slider

I am not sure what is going on with my slider.

[[image: This is the slider when it shows up]]

```html
.big-container {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.question {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 242, 0.507);
}
.answer {
  display: block;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000088;
  size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-container">
  <label class="question">Tolerance (%):
    <div class="answer">
      <div><mat-slider thumbLabel tickInterval="10" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="1"></mat-slider></div>
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

I would like to have a similar UI as in the slider example seen at https://material.angular.io/components/slider/overview
What should I do? I don't see any unavailable dependencies and the slider works, but does not show up well.

Comment: Could you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) example?

Comment: It would be hard to reproduce without getting all my code in it (the app is kind of huge ). I think its because I installed wrongly and did not set up a theme. Is that possible?

Comment: -- This is solved I installed angular Cli then used ng add@angular/material. ( I only used npm add @angular material before)

Comment: Maybe. Try to reinstall. Or some styles have more specificity

Answer (score 0):

The angular material installation was not installed correctly. Thus, there was no theme installed. I used ng add@angular/material after using npm install -g @angular/cli to get the cli. I selected a theme and it showed up properly.